# Trouble posting user credentials with app engine url fetch

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cookies

I'm developing an application which needs to be able to login to a website on a user's behalf and do some html scraping. Like many other developers, app engine is giving me trouble when it comes to cookie management. The server I'm logging in to sends a redirect after the initial POST, which then sends another redirect to the final landing page. As far as I can tell the purpose is for the server to verify cookies are working. I've stitched together the following helper class from other answers on SO.

```
public class Utilities {

    public static String smartPost(String url, String data) throws IOException {
        // storage for cookies between redirects
        Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        response.append(url);
        URL resource = new URL(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) resource.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                "" + Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(data);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        url = connection.getHeaderField("location");

        while (url != null) {
            // Get Cookies
            getCookiesFromConnection(connection, cookies);
            URL redirectResource = new URL(url);
            response.append(url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) redirectResource.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            addCookiesToConnection(connection, cookies);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            url = connection.getHeaderField("location");
            connection.disconnect();
        }

        // Arrived at final location
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();

        return response.toString();
    }

    static void addCookiesToConnection(HttpURLConnection c,
            Map<String, String> storage) {
        StringBuilder cookieStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry<String, String> e : storage.entrySet()) {
            cookieStringBuilder.append(e.getKey());
            cookieStringBuilder.append("=");
            cookieStringBuilder.append(e.getValue());
            cookieStringBuilder.append(";");
        }
        c.setRequestProperty("Cookies", cookieStringBuilder.toString());
    }

    static void getCookiesFromConnection(HttpURLConnection c,
            Map<String, String> storage) {
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = c.getHeaderFields();
        for (Entry<String, List<String>> e : headers.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie")) {
                for (String cookieHeader : e.getValue()) {
                    String cookie = cookieHeader.substring(0,
                            cookieHeader.indexOf(";"));
                    String key = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
                    String value = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1);
                    storage.put(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My goal was to handle the redirects manually and pass the cookies through to the final page. It works fine on the development server, but I don't think it's my code doing the work, but rather the default behavior on the local server. Anyone have experience implementing this kind of functionality on the production server? I'm pretty inexperienced with the java.net package, so I could be awfully far from a solution.

I originally tried implementing this in Go, but I had the same results and figured it was just my utter lack of experience with Go. Java will be easier for html scraping anyway because of Jsoup, but I'm not opposed to using python or go on this if that will make it easier somehow. It's a pretty small piece of a large project and I'm not too far in to switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for a few days, I found this [article](http://everydayscripting.blogspot.com/2009/08/google-app-engine-cookie-handling-with.html)
Which does exactly what I was trying to do, in python. I've decided to use python for this project and I will user BeautifulSoup for the html scraping. Still unsure what was wrong with my code initially.